# Replacing a value in a row of a column with a function of a list formed by corresponding elements of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function of a list defined by user (function f). Say, it's the sum of the elements of the list but can be another function.

Then I have a dataframe with two columns: 'pred' that contains a list of numbers and 'value' which contains a single number. Value -1 is a placeholder that needs to be updated.

```
import pandas as pd

def f(my_list):
    return sum(my_list)

data = {'pred':[[],[1],[1],[1],[2],[2,3],[2,4],[3],[3,4],[4],[6,7,9,10]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = df.index + 1

df.loc[5,'value'] = 1
df.loc[8,'value'] = 0
df.loc[10,'value'] = 2
df.loc[11,'value'] = 100
df.value = df.value.fillna(-1).astype(int) #placeholder, the values cannot be negative

print(df)
```

```
             pred  value
1              []     -1
2             [1]     -1
3             [1]     -1
4             [1]     -1
5             [2]      1
6          [2, 3]     -1
7          [2, 4]     -1
8             [3]      0
9          [3, 4]     -1
10            [4]      2
11  [6, 7, 9, 10]    100
```

Now I have to go through the rows of the df in the reverse order and update -1 values with function f of the list of values of those who have i in their pred list. It is guaranteed that i will not appear in the lists in the pred column in rows 1 to i.

In this example we should have:

```
value in row 9: f([100]) = 100;
value in row 7: f([100]) = 100;
value in row 6: f([100]) = 100;
value in row 4: f([2, 100, 100]) = 202;
value in row 3: f([100, 0, 100]) = 200;
value in row 2: f([1, 100, 100]) = 201;
value in row 1: f([201, 200, 202]) = 603.
```

So, need help on how to make a loop to get that done.

```
for i in range(len(df),0,-1):
  if df.loc[i,'value'] == -1:
    df.loc[i,'value'] = ???
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: "*update -1 values with function f of the list of values of those who have i in their pred list*" is quite unclear. Starting on row 9, why would you run `f([100])`? Where is `[100]` coming from?

Comment: So, we go through the rows in the backward order until we reach -1 as a value. The first one is row 9. Its value has to be updated. We see that "9" is in pred column of row 11, the corresponding value in row 11 is 100. So we form list [100] and replace -1 in row 9 with f([100]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can create a dictionary of indices that are referenced by other indices. Then loop over the -1 indices in reverse and index the relevant rows to pass to `f`:

```
s = df['pred'].explode()
dic = s.index.groupby(s)
# {1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [5, 6, 7], 3: [6, 8, 9], ...}

for i in df.index[df['value'].eq(-1)][::-1]:
    df.loc[i, 'value'] = f(df.loc[dic.get(i, []), 'value'])
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
             pred  value
1              []    603
2             [1]    201
3             [1]    200
4             [1]    202
5             [2]      1
6          [2, 3]    100
7          [2, 4]    100
8             [3]      0
9          [3, 4]    100
10            [4]      2
11  [6, 7, 9, 10]    100
```

Breaking down the loop step by step, this does:

```
df.loc[9, 'value'] = f(df.loc[[11], 'value'])       # f([100])
df.loc[7, 'value'] = f(df.loc[[11], 'value'])       # f([100])
df.loc[6, 'value'] = f(df.loc[[11], 'value'])       # f([100])
df.loc[4, 'value'] = f(df.loc[[7, 9, 10], 'value']) # f([100, 100, 2])
df.loc[3, 'value'] = f(df.loc[[6, 8, 9], 'value'])  # f([100, 0, 100])
df.loc[2, 'value'] = f(df.loc[[5, 6, 7], 'value'])  # f([1, 100, 100])
df.loc[1, 'value'] = f(df.loc[[2, 3, 4], 'value'])  # f([201, 200, 202])
```